# Unphysical gauge boson polarizations in non-abelian gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, polarization, ward-identity

I am learning P&S's chapter 16 , quantization of non-abelian gauge theory.(all my ref. formula in this post lie in P&S's book) I am puzzled for the logic of the unphysical polarization of gauge bosons.

First, for the theory of QED, we initially proved the Ward identity in section 7.4,
$$k_{\mu}\mathcal{M}^{\mu}(k)=0 \tag{7.64} $$
then for longitudinal polarization, $k^{\mu}=(k,0,0,k)$, we will have
$$k\mathcal{M}^0(k)-k\mathcal{M}^3(k)=0 \tag{5.80} $$
and so for QED, we can see that we can only have two transverse physical degrees of freedom regarding the gauge boson.

Now, for a non-Abelian gauge theory, in section 16.1, the book first wants to prove the Ward identity. This requires one external gauge boson that will have only a transverse degree freedom in tree-level diagrams with three gauge boson vertex. But, if not, then the Ward identity is not satisfied.

So does this mean in the most general case, that gauge bosons need to have longitudinal polarization? Since we haven't proved something like the Ward identity in QED?

Another point is how to understand this unphysical polarization? Ghost field is unphysical, I can understand that. Ghosts cannot appear in tree-level diagrams, and our physical Hilbert space doesn't include ghosts. But how about non-abelian polarization?